# Character Array initialization

Tags: c, string

I'm currently playing a bit with C and trying to understand strings. Can somebody please explain why this is working:

```
char test[] = "test";
```

And why the following does not?

```
char test[255];
test = "test";
```

Answer (score 8):

Because this is an *initialization*:

```
char test[] = "test";
```

and this is an *assignment*:

```
test = "test";
```

and you cannot assign arrays in C (and strings in C are just arrays).

Your best bet is to copy the string using `strcpy()` (or to be safe, [`strncpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/)).

Answer (score 5):

C doesn't allow you to assign values to an entire array except when it's initialized.

The correct way to copy a string into an existing array is with `strcpy`:

```
char test[255];
strcpy(test,"test");
```

Answer (score 0):

even though what you say looks obvious,it is incorrect.you can't directly assign a string to a character array.you could try and use strcpy() function.

Answer (score 0):

Because "test" is a *pointer* and test is an *array*. You can always use strcpy() though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately C doesnot support direct assigment of string(As it invloves more than 1 memory address). You must rather use strcpy or memcpy functions.

well 
yeah

```
 test[0]='t' works (since your accessing one memory location at the time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an array directly because it is an unmodifiable lvalue. But you can use an indirectly assignment like:

```
typedef struct { char s[100]; } String;

int main()
{
  char a[100] = "before";
  assert( sizeof a >= sizeof(String) );
  puts( a );
  *(String*)a = *(String*) "after";
  puts( a );
  return 0;
}
```