# Issue with structs and strings

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
typedef struct{
  char name[64];
} Cat;

Cat createCat(char name[64]) {
  Cat newCat;

  newCat.name = name;

  return newCat;
}
```

It compiles with the following error message:

> incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[64]' from type 'char
>   *'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `memcpy()` or `strcpy()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Character Array initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255984/character-array-initialization)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array decay to pointers when passed to functions. So:

```
Cat createCat(char name[64]) {
```

is the same as:

```
Cat createCat(char* name) {
```

and the line:

```
newCat.name = name;
```

is attempting to assign a `char*` to a `char[]`, as the error states. As [Mystical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) has already commented, you need to use [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) or [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) (or [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)) to copy `name` to `newCat.name`. If you use `memcpy()` you *must* remember to null terminate `newCat.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes. You're returning an automatic (stack-based) variable from a function. That will die horribly when the stack frame is popped and the memory goes away. You need to dynamically allocate a `Cat` structure and copy the `name` data into it. Don't forget to call `free()` when you're done with the memory.

```
Cat *createCat(char name[64])
{
Cat *tmpCat;
tmpCat=malloc(sizeof(Cat));
strncpy(Cat.name,name,64); // <- or 63 to make sure name is NULL-terminated
return tmpCat;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. A copy of the local stack allocated `Cat` is being returned so the posted code is fine in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two bugs. The first is that you are allocating memory on the stack. Whenever you declare a variable like this:

```
int hello = 5;
char test;
Cat newCat;
```

You are allocating memory on the stack. This memory is freed as soon as the function returns. To make something more permanent, you need to manually allocate memory in the heap with the malloc function. This memory will remain valid until you release it at a later date by calling `free()`. Additionally, you need to use `strncpy()` to copy strings, you can not simply copy the pointer.

```
Cat* createCat(char* name)
{
     Cat* newCat = malloc(sizeof(Cat));
     if(!newCat)
     {
            printf("Error allocating memory for cat\n");
            exit(-1);
     }
     //copy in the string, leave a null terminator on the string
     strncpy(newCat.name, name, 63);
     newCat.name[63] = '\0'; 
     return newCat;
}
```

Comment: Returning stack-allocated structs is fine, a copy is returned. Only pointers to stack-allocated data suffer from the problem that the data vanishes.